# Is there a multidimensional database model?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, rdbms, database

What is the essential difference between relational and multidimensional databases?

I just don't get it. The arguments I find on the Internet do not make it clear to me, in fact they mostly do not make any sense at all. Here are some examples:

- Relational models are generally complex; multidimensional model are simple
- Relational models are flat, ie. tables are two-dimensional; multidimensional models can have more then two dimensions
- Relational models are usually normalized; multidimensional models are highly denormalized
- Relational models store data in tables; multidimensional models store data in cubes
- etc...

The majority of texts try to explain how multidimensional databases are *better* than relational databases (in terms of performance, ease of use and maintenance, etc.), but they do not explain what the *formal difference* between them really is. To clarify:

Relational databases implement the relational model; if multidimensional databases are really different from relational databases, then they must implement a different (non-relational) model, because otherwise they would still be relational, right? So my question is:

Is there really a different model for multidimensional databases? If so, is it formally defined and where can I find texts about it? And if it is not the case, what *is* the difference?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a 'Multidimensional database' is? Like a Relational database would be SQL-Server or MySQL etc etc.

Comment: @simonatrcl: I haven't used it, but [Oracle Essbase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essbase) seems to be one.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "multidimensional database". Your own link links text "multidimensional modeling" to the wiki OLAP article. Which in turn says OLAP "encompasses relational". Please clarify via post edits not comments. Please include everything needed for your question as text in your question, with links just for more detail. Your question is complicated by relational misconceptions. Relations/tables are multidimensional--each column is a dimension/axis. Pictures of relations/tables are "flat" & "two-dimensional". "Dimensional modeling" is part of (usually, relational) OLAP.

Comment: There is no reason to leave the RM (relational model) to do OLTP or OLAP. Most OLAP (including "dimensional modeling") presentations & products do not incorporate the RM enough, and even wrongly say that the RM is inapplicable. Very roughly speaking, dimensional modeling is OLAP & talk of multidimensional databases just doesn't understand the RM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about the differences between OnLine Transaction Processing databases (aka OLTP, e.g. SQL Server, My SQL) and On Line Analytical Processing databases (aka OLAP, e.g. Essbase, Sql Server Analysys Services SSAS).

They have very different purposes. For a store of data for a usual application (web site, desktop order processing etc etc) you would have to use an OLTP db as it's optimised for Transactions: basically CRUD operations and some reporting. An OLAP db, by contrast, is horrible at CRUD (you actually can't do CRUD in any OLAP db I know of), but fantastic at Reporting. The two work together.

Generally, your OLTP db is the workhorse. At some interval (daily, weekly, more often, less often) you extract either the whole OLTP db or just new bits into the OLAP db for reporting.

The internal structures of the two are quite different. An OLTP should have normalised tables and its code (the actual servers code, not ours) is optimised for a mix of read/write. An OLAP db is very denormalised (hence conceptually simpler in some ways) and optimised for reading. The benefits are such that an OLTP db I was using for reporting had a number of queries run daily which each took 45 mins plus. When we added a daily extract to an OLAP db, those reports ran in less than 5 seconds.

However, remember that you can't use an OLAP database for simple CRUD operations, and that an OLAP db will have extra licencing costs, management issues, and update timing issues: the users will get their data super fast, but it'll be out of date by some time and cost them extra. Also, they can be quite difficult to maintain.

Comment: Sorry, but **no**, that's not what I'm asking about. Basically, my question is: *what model do multidimensional databases implement*? I am not asking what they are good or bad for, or how they should be used. For examle, when you talk about normalization, you are usually talking about relational databases, since normalization is applied to relations. Normalization of multidimensional databases would be different, unless multidimensional databases are in fact relational. But then, what does it mean for a database to be multidimensional?

Comment: OK, but your question was at such a level that I thought this was what you're after. There is no agreed model for OLAP db's, to my knowledge, in the way that the Relational model exists with a mathematical basis, although there are obviously a number different implementations. Look for Star Schema versus Snowflake schema, and get some technical books on OLAP processing - although they are pretty complex and as a normal dev and not a Computer Scientist you won't need such a book.

Comment: So, there is no formal model for these databases. This is sad, but Ok, I'll accept this as the answer. ;)